# How to get list of devices thst are connected to router using program

Tags: router

Using c programing i need to display mac address of the devices which are connected to router on terminal.I tried with so many things bt still i am not getting the exact output.Else any command is there to get that details please share.i am doing project based on this so please if anyone know means share the answers.

Comment: Um, you might want to tag this with more things than just router.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about doing it with C, but I have a look at ettercap you could use some command line script to to easily get info about all connected devices a local network.

Comment: how i use "ettercp" to lis the connected devicess. i'm working on linux plateform and my router is openwrt installed. so ples help me to get that list it's important for ma college project.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is to write your your arp-scan.

To do this basically you'll need to write or use existing C based ping code. Apple has a nice simple ping.

Here is the link to apple's simple ping - 
[simplePing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SimplePing/Listings/SimplePing_m.html)

Then you will want to open your devices arp-table. This will vary based on device but there should be some way to make C code compatible across a narrow range of devices.

Here is an interesting code review involving what you are looking for. 
[Post is here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58097/parsing-arp-cache-in-c)